# Infinite loop when reading from socket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have the following code on the server side:

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
int x;
while(true) {
      x = in.read();
      if(x < 0) break;
      System.out.print((char)x);
}
```

The client is properly connected and sends some string to the server. But the while loop runs forever. How to detect when the end of the input stream is reached.

Comment: Can you show us what is the output?

Comment: What's the type of `x`?

Comment: @AmanArora why should he change it to `x>0` ? This won't detect the end but will cause the loop to stop when the first byte arrives

Comment: Show more code, like how you create `in`

Comment: @HyperZ I thought the code should come out of loop as soon as some data arrives in the stream

Comment: I suspect this isn't looping forever, but rather blocking on the `read()`

Comment: they way you are doing it, the only time you will get a `-1` is when the socket is actually closed; usually by the other end. This will not work like it would for reading a file.

Comment: You will be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562370/how-to-identify-end-of-inputstream-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`while((x = in.read()) >= 0)
    System.out.println((char)x);`

in.read() returns the read byte from the stream. If there is no byte to be read, the method will return -1.

Comment: How is this different to what they already have? And why is `0` not valid?

Comment: this will not work for sockets any better than the original code, this is not an answer