# read end of response in java readLine()

Tags: java, android, ios, sockets, bufferedreader

```
    try {
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            mSocket.getInputStream()));
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        String messageStr = null;
                        messageStr = input.readLine();
                        if (messageStr != null) {
                            updateMessages(messageStr, false);
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(CLIENT_TAG, "Server loop error: ", e);
                }
```

I am using the above code in a thread for receiving responses from socket connection.
In Android it works correctly as I used `out.println()` for sending data,  but when the device is connected to ios and starts to receive data it cannot identify the end and is only received when the connection is closed. Is there any alternative methods other than `readLine()` and how to use in the above code.

Comment: Have a look at [how to identify end of inputstream in java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5562415/4935567) and I think you will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work better.

```
try 
{
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()));
    String messageStr = "";
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && (messageStr = input.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        updateMessages(messageStr, false);
    }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e(CLIENT_TAG, "Server loop error: ", e);
}
```