# loop function freezes on start spigot

Tags: java, while-loop, minecraft

I'm making a plugin for my Minecraft server which updates an API every 5 seconds with the amount of players online. Every time the server starts up, it gets stuck while enabling the plugin.

This is the function:

```
public static void playerListLoop(String status, int onlinePlayers) {

        Boolean on = true;

        try {
            while (on = true) {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.14:3000");
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("x-_id", "518747784");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("x-api-key", "7");
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    String urlParameters = "{\"survival\": {\"status\": \"" + status + "\", \"players\": \"" + onlinePlayers + "\"}}";
                    byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())){
                        wr.write(postData);
                    }

                    StringBuilder content;

                    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                        String line;
                        content = new StringBuilder();

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            content.append(line);
                            content.append(System.lineSeparator());
                        }
                    }

                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your InputStream return a `null` when there is no more input? Isn't `readLine` a blocking operation - won't it wait for next input?

Comment: very true, would I put an else statement under the while != null. and if so what would i put in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify end of InputStream in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562370/how-to-identify-end-of-inputstream-in-java)

Comment: that doesn't explain how to end an input stream

Answer (score 0):

Like @Amongalen said your method `playerListLoop()` is a blocking operation. See, you start a `while` loop, but the loop in your code goes on forever as neither your `on` variable gets changed, nor there is something like `break;`. That means your plugin gets stuck in this method.

What you need to do is either create a new thread and have your loop run in that thread, or (and what I would recommend) you use the `BukkitScheduler` prebuild into Spigot.

---

### Sync Tasks

First we save the id so we will be able to cancel the task again:

```
int taskID;
```

Then we create our task:

- For that you need an instance of the class extending `JavaPlugin`.
- I use a lambda expression here, but you can also refer to a method.
- In this case, the 0 is the delay in in game ticks
- And the 100 is the time in ticks between every loop (1 second = 20 ticks)

```java
taskID = Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(YourClass.instance, () -> {
    // update your API
}, 0, 100);
```

To cancel your task you do:

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTask(taskID);
```

---

### Async Tasks

If you want your task to be async you need to do it a bit different.

This time we save our task using the `BukkitTask` interface:

```
BukkitTask task;
```

Then it's quite similar to sync tasks:

```
task = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimerAsynchronously(YourClass.instance, () -> {
    // update your API
}, 0, 100);
```

And to cancel the task you then do:

```
task.cancel();
```

Comment: Since it is a network request you might as well schedule it async. Just be careful what you do before and after the call

Comment: how do i then call this in the main class?

Comment: I edited the answer to include async tasks.